# logging to a file from bonobo etl

Tags: python, logging, bonobo-etl

I have written a bonobo script to extract some data, and I would like to use python's logging module to write some status messages to a file while my job runs.  I've done the following:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename=INFO["LOGFILE_PATH"]+r'\bonobo_job_'+date.today().isoformat(),
                filemode='a',
                format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

If I simply run the script in Pycharm, it logs to the file as I would expect.  But if I run it from the command line with the bonobo run command, it ignores the filename and logs to stdout.  How do I fix this?  Is there a flag or environment variable I need to set somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,I figured it out.  For some reason, basicConfig doesn't work.  I had to use getLogger and add a FileHandler.  So in **main** I did this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('bonobo_logger')
ch = logging.FileHandler(logfilename)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

Then in every node in my graph where I wanted to do logging, I called:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('bonobo_logger')
```

and used the logger object to write out all messages.  If anyone knows a better way of doing it, please let me know.